# Reloading the same page based on a toggle button preserving the paramters

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I have a page where I have a static list containing the list of products which are again grouped into product groups.I have a toggle button in the JSP page which shuffles between the enabled and disabled products .Code for my toggle button is as follows

```
 <h:commandButton value="retrieve"  image="#{displayProductsBean.productsToggleImage}" actionListener="#{displayProductsBean.fetchProductsBasedOnStatus}">
     <c:choose>
      <c:when test="${displayProductsBean.productFetchCriteria=='0'}">
        <f:attribute name="buttonSelected" value="1" />
      </c:when>
      <c:otherwise>
        <f:attribute name="buttonSelected" value="0" />
      </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>

    </h:commandButton>
```

Now in the managed bean I am able to get the value of the button selected and have logic to retrieve either enabled or disabled products 
But I don't know how would I get back to the same page and also I don't want the list to be reloaded again from the DB.Code in my bean class is as follows

```
public void fetchProductsBasedOnStatus(ActionEvent event)
    {
        System.out.println("The fetchProductsBasedOnStatus in bean is called"); 
        String selected = (String) event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("buttonSelected");
        System.out.println("The value of toggle button is"+selected);
        setProductFetchCriteria(Integer.parseInt(selected));
        System.out.println("The value of toggle button is"+this.toString());

    }
```

Somebody please help me resolve this .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *But I don't know how would I get back to the same page*

Just return `null` or `void` in action method.

> *and also I don't want the list to be reloaded again from the DB*

Just don't do that? If you keep the bean in the view scope and load the lists in the (post)constructor, then the same lists will be kept as long as the enduser is interacting with the same view. You should only not use JSTL tags as it breaks the view scope.

Your code can be simplified as follows:

```html
<h:commandButton value="retrieve" image="#{bean.showDisabledProducts ? 'enabled' : 'disabled'}.png" action="#{bean.toggle}">
    <f:ajax render="@form" />
</h:commandButton>

<h:dataTable value="#{bean.products}" ...>
    ...
</h:dataTable>
```

with

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean {

    private boolean showDisabledProducts;
    private List<Product> enabledProducts;
    private List<Product> disabledProducts;

    @EJB
    private ProductService service;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        enabledProducts = service.listEnabledProducts();
        disabledProducts = service.listDisabledProducts();
    }

    public void toggle() {
        showDisabledProducts = !showDisabledProducts;
    }

    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        return showDisabledProducts ? disabledProducts : enabledProducts;
    }

    public boolean isShowDisabledProducts() {
        return showDisabledProducts;
    }

}
```

Comment: using the above annotations ManagedBean
ViewScoped
 is showing error to me...These questions might sound very trivial but am a starter in JSF...One more thing the toggle attribute needs to be set to the managed bean before the  reload happens but it is not getting set ...

Comment: Which error then? Why don't you tell about the error in detail? Error messages usually contain the answer to the problem. If you don't understand the message nor can interpret it, then you should share it with us so that we can explain it in layman's terms so that you finally understand the problem. You know, once a problem is *understood* the solution is obvious.

Comment: To simplify my question ..when I get back to the managed bean via action listener method can i recreate the managed bean setting a value which I am sending via the attribute above.I have a ProductAction class where I have a bean containing the list of products which actually loads enabled r disabled products based on an attribute productFetchCriteria which can be 0 or 1 depending on the value passed from the jsp page via attribute....

Comment: It is actually not recognizing this annotation and asking to create one

Comment: Wait.. Are you using JSF2 with JSP? JSP does not support many of new JSF2 features such as `<f:ajax>`? JSP is **deprecated** and succeeded by Facelets. You should be using Facelets instead.

Comment: The annotation needs to be imported from `javax.faces.bean` package. But after all, are you really using JSF 2.0? This annotation is introduced in JSF 2.0. When using JSF 1.x you will indeed not be able to import it.

Comment: There's your root problem. Go read JSF 2.x tutorials, not JSF 1.x tutorials. You can find an overview at the bottom of our JSF wiki page: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info